# Firebase Function Emulator Unsupported function type on functionName., Expected either httpsTrigger or eventTrigger

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I juste update node 14 to 16.

But now i have a Warning in my firebase emulator suite logs for cloud_functions

[image: firebase emulator suite warning]

> Unsupported function type on functionName., Expected either httpsTrigger or eventTrigger

there is the dependancies for the nodejs's functions package.json

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/geopoint": "^1.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.12.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^10.3.1",
    "ts-geopoint": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
```

Do you know the problem ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you please include the code in `sendPasswordResetEmail` on your question for us to  be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: sorry. Problem solved but i don't remember how since long time. Sorry, i forgot to answer

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is already fixed (at least on master ).
See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4313 and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/4314.

**Update:**

As Baptiste mentioned, the bug is fixed in version 10.4.0.

Comment: Thank very much, this is fixed now in firebase-tools 10.4.0 see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4320